# IOC , Class Factory, Open/Closed

Tags: vb.net, inversion-of-control

I have a question about IOC, factories, and the Open/Closed principle.

consider, if you will,  the following factory

```
public function PODocument( _type as string) as IPODocument

      dim d as new PODocument
      if _type = "service" then 
         d.header = new ServicePOHeader()
         d.details = new ServicePOLineItems()
      else if _type = "merchandise" then 
         d.header = new MerchandisePOHeader()
         d.details = new MerchandisePOLineItems()
      end if 

    return d

end function
```

This is working for me and I can nicely have a webpage show information about heterogeneous collections.

My challenge is that today someone told me sometimes a certain customer will order a service and merchandise together. Come on, who among us could have seen that coming?

So I write a new set of providers that handle the added complexity, changed the factory to include a case for the new type, I'm back off and running.

However, I have violated the open/closed principle by changing the factory, which was released to production. 
Is there a way to set this up so that I am not constantly changing the factory?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't be this concerned, those principles are not meant to be followed dogmatic, your design is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The simplest example for your case would be to define a factory class for each `_type`, and name them `ServiceFactory`, `MerchandiseFactory`, etc, or put a `<PODocumentType("Service")>` etc on them.

Then just find all factories (for example, using reflection), put them in a `Dictionary(Of String, IPODocumentFactory)` and select correct one based on key.

In a more complicated case, `IPODocumentFactory` interface may include `CanCreate()` method in addition to `Create()`. Then you can select a factory on the list based on its opinion about current situation.

Note that the discovery and list resolution support is often provided out of the box by DI frameworks such as Unity or Autofac.

Comment: Thank you Andy, these are all useful design suggestions. I probably need to just buckle down and investigate the DI frameworks. I have been avoiding that like the plague. Of the 2 you mention, do you have a preference?

Comment: I always use Autofac when I have a choice. I did some comparison of IoC frameworks a while ago and it seems to be the best thing feature-wise. Also it provides a Module system out of the box if you do not mind your assemblies referencing Autofac directly.